# CSS change header height based on width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I'm designing my first responsive website, and I've already run into a little problem which I can't seem to solve.

As you can see at https://jsfiddle.net/n9xh4cLm/1/, there's a main container which partly overlaps the header image. When you change the width of the frame, all the elements are sized down, but the main container doesn't overlap the header anymore. Is there a way to set the height of the header to, say, `75%` of the header image, which is responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are making a responsive website sooner or later, imho,  you may need to introduce `media queries`.

So this is what I would do in your case. Something like adding:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) { 
header {height: 70px;}
}
@media (max-width: 700px) { 
header {height: 50px;}
}
@media (max-width: 400px) { 
header {height: 30px;}
}
```

change the different steps to whatever window width you want your header to get smaller.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n9xh4cLm/6/)**

Comment: Anytime. Glad I could help. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewport value instead of ems, pxs or pts.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

In your case try this

```
.responsive img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n9xh4cLm/3/)

Comment: Depends on what browsers you are supporting. `vh` has limited support on ie.

http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Although setting the image height to `100%` does fix the main container to  a certain point in the image, it also prevents the image from scaling it's height, which leads to a weird stretched image. What I want is if the width of the viewport is twice as small, make the height of the image and the height of the header twice as small too, which leads to the main container being raised. How would I do that?